# Converting RGB frames to YUV420P using FFmpeg/C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-encoding, libavcodec, libav

I tried a code [based on this tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.c). What this does is it writes first 5 frames of a video into memory in RGB format. I need to convert these RGB frames to YUV420P format so that I can pass them to YUV420P encoder. I tried using the `sws_scale` but then the resulting frames lose color information and also suffer from scaling issues. Also, looked at various questions but none gives a working solution. I am completely new to FFmpeg library and working on various tutorials to get a grip on it. I hope somebody can suggest a nice solution. Many thanks for your inputs!

Following is the code:

```
#include <ffmpeg/avcodec.h>
#include <ffmpeg/avformat.h>

#include <stdio.h>

void SaveFrame(AVFrame *pFrame, int width, int height, int iFrame) {
  FILE *pFile;
  char szFilename[32];
  int  y;

  // Open file
  sprintf(szFilename, "frame%d.ppm", iFrame);
  pFile=fopen(szFilename, "wb");
  if(pFile==NULL)
    return;

  // Write header
  fprintf(pFile, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);

  // Write pixel data
  for(y=0; y<height; y++)
    fwrite(pFrame->data[0]+y*pFrame->linesize[0], 1, width*3, pFile);

  // Close file
  fclose(pFile);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
  int             i, videoStream;
  AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx;
  AVCodec         *pCodec;
  AVFrame         *pFrame; 
  AVFrame         *pFrameRGB;
  AVPacket        packet;
  int             frameFinished;
  int             numBytes;
  uint8_t         *buffer;

  if(argc < 2) {
    printf("Please provide a movie file\n");
    return -1;
  }
  // Register all formats and codecs
  av_register_all();

  // Open video file
  if(av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, 0, NULL)!=0)
    return -1; // Couldn't open file

  // Retrieve stream information
  if(av_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx)<0)
    return -1; // Couldn't find stream information

  // Dump information about file onto standard error
  dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, argv[1], 0);

  // Find the first video stream
  videoStream=-1;
  for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO) {
      videoStream=i;
      break;
    }
  if(videoStream==-1)
    return -1; // Didn't find a video stream

  // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
  pCodecCtx=pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;

  // Find the decoder for the video stream
  pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
  if(pCodec==NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec!\n");
    return -1; // Codec not found
  }
  // Open codec
  if(avcodec_open(pCodecCtx, pCodec)<0)
    return -1; // Could not open codec

  // Allocate video frame
  pFrame=avcodec_alloc_frame();

  // Allocate an AVFrame structure
  pFrameRGB=avcodec_alloc_frame();
  if(pFrameRGB==NULL)
    return -1;

  // Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
  numBytes=avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_RGB24, pCodecCtx->width,
                  pCodecCtx->height);
  buffer=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

  // Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in pFrameRGB
  // Note that pFrameRGB is an AVFrame, but AVFrame is a superset
  // of AVPicture
  avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, buffer, PIX_FMT_RGB24,
         pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

  // Read frames and save first five frames to disk
  i=0;
  while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) {
    // Is this a packet from the video stream?
    if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
      // Decode video frame
      avcodec_decode_video(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, 
               packet.data, packet.size);

      // Did we get a video frame?
      if(frameFinished) {
    // Convert the image from its native format to RGB
    img_convert((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, PIX_FMT_RGB24, 
                    (AVPicture*)pFrame, pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, 
                    pCodecCtx->height);

    // Save the frame to disk
    if(++i<=5)
      SaveFrame(pFrameRGB, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 
            i);
      }
    }

    // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
    av_free_packet(&packet);
  }

  // Free the RGB image
  av_free(buffer);
  av_free(pFrameRGB);

  // Free the YUV frame
  av_free(pFrame);

  // Close the codec
  avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);

  // Close the video file
  av_close_input_file(pFormatCtx);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to completely understand what you're doing here. You have frames that are RGB24 and you want them YUV to encode, and then you want to decode and convert back to RGB24 to display them... is that correct?

Comment: @Jack Yes thats the whole scenario. I have RGB frames. I want to convert them to YUV420P format, encode and decode using YUV420P encoder-decoder and finally convert the decoded images back to RGB to display them.

Comment: There is no sense in producing RGB from decoder, only to convert them back to YUV for encoding. What decoder does when you ask for RGB, it decodes YUV, and then converts it to RGB internally, thus - double work.

Answer (score 3):

You copied and pasted old code, that will not even compile with recent libav*, from someone else's website. You are asking about sws_scale, and this code doesn't even use it. So the code  is 100% unrelated to the question. On top of that, you have asked this question before, and I have answered it. [ffmpeg: RGB to YUV conversion loses color and scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938674/ffmpeg-rgb-to-yuv-conversion-loses-color-and-scale)