# Convert individual pixel values from RGB to YUV420 and save the frame - C++

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, video-encoding, libavcodec

I have been working with RGB->YUV420 conversion for sometime using the FFmpeg library. Already tried the `sws_scale` functionality but its not working well. Now, I have decided to convert each pixel individually, using colorspace conversion formulae. So, following is the code that gets me few frames and allows me to access individual R,G,B values of each pixel:

```
// Read frames and save first five frames to disk
    i=0;
    while((av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) && (i<5)) 
    {
        // Is this a packet from the video stream?
        if(packet.stream_index==videoStreamIdx) 
        {   
            /// Decode video frame            
            avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

            // Did we get a video frame?
            if(frameFinished) 
            {
                i++;
                sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, (const uint8_t * const *)pFrame->data,
                          pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height,
                          pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);

                int x, y, R, G, B;
                uint8_t *p = pFrameRGB->data[0];
                for(y = 0; y < h; y++)
                {  
                    for(x = 0; x < w; x++) 
                    {
                        R = *p++;
                        G = *p++;
                        B = *p++;
                        printf(" %d-%d-%d ",R,G,B);
                    }
                }

                SaveFrame(pFrameRGB, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, i);
            }
        }

        // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
        av_free_packet(&packet);
    }
```

I read [online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917087.aspx) that to convert RGB->YUV420 or vice-versa, one should first convert to YUV444 format. So, its like: RGB->YUV444->YUV420. How do I implement this in C++?

Also, here is the `SaveFrame()` function used above. I guess this will also have to change a little since YUV420 stores data differently. How to take care of that?

```
void SaveFrame(AVFrame *pFrame, int width, int height, int iFrame)
{
    FILE *pFile;
    char szFilename[32];
    int  y;

    // Open file
    sprintf(szFilename, "frame%d.ppm", iFrame);
    pFile=fopen(szFilename, "wb");
    if(pFile==NULL)
        return;

    // Write header
    fprintf(pFile, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);

    // Write pixel data
    for(y=0; y<height; y++)
        fwrite(pFrame->data[0]+y*pFrame->linesize[0], 1, width*3, pFile);

    // Close file
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

Can somebody please suggest? Many thanks!!!

Comment: why reinventing the wheel ? what was your issue with the ffmpeg function ? because it should work!

Comment: @alexbuisson I tried that but it loses color and scale information. Here is it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938674/ffmpeg-rgb-to-yuv-conversion-loses-color-and-scale

Somebody suggested a solution but the problems that occured couldn't be solved.

Comment: Even if you convert the planes to YUV444 manually, What are you going to use to reduce the resolution of the U/V planes to achieve YUV420? The best tool for that job is... You guessed it sws_scale! Your RGB/YUV444 implementation is also going to be MUCH slower. You need to learn how to use sws_scale. you are basically spamming stackoverflow at this point.

Comment: @szatmary I thought I could average the 2x2 blocks for both U and V channels. Won't that help?
Regarding sws_scale, you did provide me the solution. But, I asked further doubts on it, due to errors I faced with your proposed solution, and that wasn't answered. I do not understand what new question to make out of it when the error message was related to your solution. Its still posted there...hope you can help...

Comment: It would work, But its not ideal. You could also ignore the U/V places and encode black and white. That would "work" also. You really are reinventing a far inferior wheel to avoid learning how to use sw_scale.

Answer (score 0):

```
void SaveFrameYUV420P(AVFrame *pFrame, int width, int height, int iFrame)
{
    FILE *pFile;
    char szFilename[32];
    int  y;

    // Open file
    sprintf(szFilename, "frame%d.yuv", iFrame);
    pFile=fopen(szFilename, "wb");
    if(pFile==NULL)
        return;

    // Write pixel data
    fwrite(pFrame->data[0], 1, width*height, pFile);
    fwrite(pFrame->data[1], 1, width*height/4, pFile);
    fwrite(pFrame->data[2], 1, width*height/4, pFile);

    // Close file
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

On Windows, you can use [irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) to see frames saved this way.   You open the frame as RAW, 24bpp format, provide width and height, and check the box "yuv420".